# WidgetKit not work for an Intent Handler to Provide Dynamic Values

Tags: ios, swiftui, sirikit, widgetkit

I am trying to implement a widget where the user can choose a city dynamically via an intent.

I followed the step by step guide provided by apple here:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/making-a-configurable-widget

I think I have done everything correctly but the result I have is always this:

[image]

I can see the list of cities but when I select one the screen goes black, as seen in the video and the debug crashes. Both on simulator and device.

**My goal is to have the city selected within the widget's getTimeline**

Here is the code I use:

**IntentHandler.swift in SiriIntent's target:**

```
import Intents

class IntentHandler: INExtension, DynamicCitySelectionIntentHandling {
    func provideCity_paramOptionsCollection(for intent: DynamicCitySelectionIntent, with completion: @escaping (INObjectCollection<City>?, Error?) -> Void) {
        let dataSource = PersistenceController.shared.getAllForecastDataCoreData()
        
        let coreDataCities: [City] = dataSource.map { cityCoreData in
            let city = City(identifier: "\(cityCoreData.cityID ?? -1)", display: cityCoreData.cityName ?? "")
            return city
        }
        
        let collection = INObjectCollection(items: coreDataCities)

        completion(collection, nil)
    }
    
    override func handler(for intent: INIntent) -> Any {
        return self
    }
}
```

**Part of code in Widget class:**

```
import WidgetKit
import SwiftUI
import Combine
import MapKit

typealias Entry = ForecastEntry

struct Provider: IntentTimelineProvider {
    
    let snapshotEntry = Entry(date: Date(), forecastViewModel: .initForPlaceholder())
    
    func placeholder(in context: Context) -> ForecastEntry {
        snapshotEntry
    }
    
    public func getSnapshot(
      for configuration: DynamicCitySelectionIntent,
      in context: Context,
      completion: @escaping (Entry) -> Void
    ) {
        let entry = snapshotEntry
        completion(entry)
    }
    
    public func getTimeline(
      for configuration: DynamicCitySelectionIntent,
      in context: Context,
      completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> Void
    ) {
        
        let currentDate = Date()
        let correctDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .second, value: 150, to: currentDate)
        WidgetServiceManager.shared.fetchWeather(forCityId: configuration.city_param?.identifier ?? "") { data in
            guard let _data = data else { return }
            let entry = Entry(date: currentDate,
                              forecastViewModel: ForecastCardViewModel(weatherModel: _data,
                                                                       isForUserPosition: false))
            let timeline = Timeline(entries: [entry],
                                    policy: .after(correctDate ?? Date()))
            completion(timeline)
        }
    }
}

@main
struct WeatherAppWidget: Widget {
    let kind: String = "WeatherAppWidget"
    
    init() {
    }
    
    var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
        IntentConfiguration(
          kind: kind,
          intent: DynamicCitySelectionIntent.self,
          provider: Provider()
        ) { entry in
            WeatherAppWidgetEntryView(entry: entry)
        }
        .configurationDisplayName("Weather Widget")
        .description("Forecasts in your location.")
        .supportedFamilies([.systemMedium, .systemSmall])
    }
}
```

**.intentdefinition file:**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
struct LargeWidgetEntry: TimelineEntry {
    let date: Date
    let configuration: ConfigurationIntent
}
```

Use configuration