# iOS Widget Configuration: How to show a loading spinner while fetching data with an IntentHandler?

Tags: ios, asynchronous, async-await, configuration, widget

My app has a widget that allows for customization. When the user chooses to edit the widget, it flips to reveal a customization pane. For example, let's say I have a weather widget and the only customization option is the city for which to show the current weather condition.

When the user taps the current city to choose a different one, I need to perform a network request to fetch the available cities that might take some time under difficult network conditions. In that scenario, my widget configuration pane appears to be broken because nothing happens when I tap on the current city. Only after several seconds (when the data has been fetched), the modal screen appears with the list of available cities.

But I want to give the user some visual feedback that something is happening while the cities are loading. How can I achieve that?

#### Note

I found [this other question on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67730800/2062785) with a GIF that shows a loading spinner (activity indicator / `ProgressView`) inside the widget configuration pane. How do I make this thing appear?

[image: Screenshot of Widget configuration pane]

#### Sample Implementation

This is my sample implementation in my `IntentHandler` to simulate a network request before returning. (Tried the same thing using a completion handler instead of the `async` function.) It doesn't show a loading spinner.

```
func provideCategoryOptionsCollection(for intent: CityIntent) async throws -> INObjectCollection<Category> {
    // Simulate async network request
    try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 5 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))
    let citiesSection: INObjectSection<City> = INObjectSection(
        title: "Cities", 
        items: [.singapore, .sydney, .honolulu]
    )
    return INObjectCollection(sections: [citiesSection])
}
```

Comment: Hi, I also have this problem, did you find a solution?

Comment: No, unfortunately I did not.

Comment: Did u find a solution for the spinner? @Mischa